# Getting the opencv moments or contour from an android path

Tags: java, android, opencv, path, contour

I have a path in a View function and I would like to get its opencv moment.

E.g. a square:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(0, 500);
path.lineTo(500, 500);
path.lineTo(500, 0);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
```

Is there an easy way to get a contour of this path or directly the moments?

I'm looking for something like:

```
MatOfPoint contour = new MatOfPoint(path);
```

or:

```
Moments m = Imgproc.moments(path);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Imgproc.fitEllipse().
In most cases it will give you almost the same answer.

```
ellipse = Imgproc.fitEllipse(new MatOfPoint2f(countor.toArray()));
```